# Conditionally make type required when other property (string literal) is present on same interface

Tags: typescript

I am creating a generic form field in React with Typescript currently shown below:

```
interface FieldProps {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    type: "email" | "text" | "textarea" | "select";
    options?: string[];
}
```

I am trying to create an interface such that if the user provides `"select"` for the prop `type` then the options prop should be required and the linter would display an error. For all other types it should be fine.

```
<Field name="email" label="Email" type="email"/> // should show no error
<Field name="country" label="Country" type="select"/> //should show error
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where union types come in, you need to split your interface definition into specific use cases like so:

```js
interface FieldPropsBase {
    name: string;
    label: string;
}

interface FieldPropsWithOptions extends FieldPropsBase {
    type: "select";
    options: string[];
}

interface FieldPropsWithoutOptions extends FieldPropsBase {
    type: "email" | "text" | "textarea";
    options?: string[];
}

type FieldProps = FieldPropsWithOptions | FieldPropsWithoutOptions;
```